# How do I switch structure to determine what class that have body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this sample:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/xby72pr9/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="test">TEST</div>
</div>
```

**CODE JS:**

```
switch (n) {   //what I need  to write instead of n
    case body:
        alert("my class is body");
        break;
    case another_class:
        alert("my class is another");
        break;
    default:
        //etc
}
```

I want simply to test have or not my class ... a class at a time, using a switch structure.

My pages on the site have different classes in body and want to apply a style only if there is a certain class ...

I hope you have understood what I meant if I did not try to explain otherwise

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want to get other class names present when any element contains `body` class?

Comment: I want to check the class body ... then apply a style, if not do anything

Comment: @Marius: check where??

Comment: Something like **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/xby72pr9/1/)**?

Answer (score 2):

you could do like this in jquery:

```
if($('.body').length){
    alert('this is body');
}
else if ($('.another_class').length)
{
    alert('another');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
switch (document.querySelector('div').classList[0]) {
    case "body":
        alert("my class is body");
        break;
    case "another_class":
        alert("my class is another");
        break;
    default:
        //etc
}
```

[fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/xby72pr9/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').each(function(){
var Class=$(this).attr('class');
switch (Class) {
    case "body":
        alert("class is +"Class);
        break;
    case "test":
        alert("class is +"Class);
        break;
    default:
        //etc
}
});
```

This might help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure what you are trying to acchieve, but adding a certain style to a child element, when the parent element's class is different, can be done without any javascript, just declare your css like this:

```
.body .test{
   styling of test inside .body in any case, overruled by anything that follows ;)
}
.body.classNameA .test{
   styling of test in case of classNameA;
}
.body.classNameB .test{
   styling of test in case of classNameB;
}
```

if the .body class is the thing that is changing, leave that out.